# Android File Association

Tags: java, android

How do I have a new file type launch my app?

For example if I have a new file type 'file.mjl' and I receive this file as an email, I want Android to associate this file type with my app and allow me to open / save it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an `intent-filter` to the activity you want to launch to work with that file.  Here is a link to a great example on that subject:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

Comment: And if I am just a user, that wants to restore some file associations?

Comment: You can go to Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications and choose the one that is the default now and click the Clear Defaults button.